# Unresolved compilation problems: The method getInput(String) is undefined for the type Main

Tags: java

Maybe I'm forgetting an import at the head, but nothing seems to work.  I'm trying to learn java and still beginner.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1=getInput("Enter First Number") ;
    String s2=getInput("Enter second Number");

    double d1=Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2=Double.parseDouble(s2);
    double result=d1+d2 ;
    System.out.println(result);

 }}
```

results in an error because the compiler doesn't recognize `getInput("");`

This is from Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        The method getInput(String) is undefined for the type Main
        The method getInput(String) is undefined for the type Main

        at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: why is this post uneditable to me?

Comment: Cause you're not cool enough yet.

Comment: @Adrian You don't have enough reputation. Your edit goes into a queue which is approved or rejected by those who have enough reputation. See [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges)

Comment: @Ktash I can edit it now (the link appeared). My rep is the same

Comment: @Adrian The link is there because you can edit it, it just goes into a queue and only appears to you until it is either approved or rejected by people with enough reputation. You get to edit it without approval at 2000 reputation. If you have any more questions, I'd check out the [faq] or we can move it to [chat].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling a getInput()-method which doesn't exist in your class. Have a look at this Java tutorial on I/O:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

Comment: Can you give me a way , to make my code work without using readBuffer,

Answer (score 1):

```
"This is from Eclipse:

Exception in thread"
```

***Eclipse*** should have warned you about this before you compiled the file with a "red" marks. Please fix them before compiling the class.

Answer (score 0):

That is because getInput is not defined. Take a look at this example to see how to get input from a user.

http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/java-get-user-input.shtml

Comment: Plz give way to make my code work without using readerBuffer ,how to make main know it

Comment: Roseindia.net is one of the worst online Java resources when it comes to "best practices" shown in the code examples. Rather refer Oracle's own tutorials instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.io.*;



BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(System.in);
String input = reader.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

What could be wrong:

1. method getInput is not implemented in Main class
2. getInput is not static, so main doesn't see it (you could change getInput to static method)
3. getInput doesn't have String signature, so it doesn't take String as parameter

Comment: so give me a way to make it, recognized by main

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now, but like everyone else has said, it looks like getInput hasn't been implemented. Meaning you haven't told the program what getInput actually does. You'll need an import, and to add the getInput method something like the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String s1=getInput("Enter First Number") ; 
        String s2=getInput("Enter second Number"); 

        double d1=Double.parseDouble(s1); 
        double d2=Double.parseDouble(s2); 
        double result=d1+d2 ; 
        System.out.println(result); 

    }
    private static String getInput(String output)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(output);
        return input.next();
    }
}
```

The getInput method here takes that string you send it and calls it 'output.' so output = "Enter First Numer" the first time you call it.

Then you create a Scanner object named 'input', which will allow you to read what the user types in the keyboard.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then you send that output message to the user:

```
System.out.println(output);
```

Finally, you return the String that was typed by the user, using your input object that will read the next thing the user types. The user will have to hit enter after typing.

```
return input.next();
```

If you have any questions about what's happening there let me know.